# changes values checkbox when I change the year

Tags: angular

I am using Angular2, I select in checkbox december the 2017, when I change a 2018 I have check december, I need that when I change the year, all the checkboxs are without check.

With this select I control the year:

```html
<select name="year" (ngModelChange)="onChangeYear()" >
...
```

Example the inputs, January:

```html
 <div class="checkbox" [ngClass]="{'disabled': checkCanEnabled(1)}">
 <input type="checkbox" id="enero" name="enero" [disabled]="checkCanEnabled(1)  || disabledPeriod" [(ngModel)]="selectedjanuary" (ngModelChange)="onChangeMonths()" >
```

Component .ts:

```js
// I get the values from my Service.

    public selectedjanuary: boolean = this.data.months.jan;
    public selectedfebruary: boolean = this.data.months.feb;
    public selectedmarch: boolean = this.data.months.mar;
    public selectedapril: boolean = this.data.months.apr;
    public selectedmay: boolean = this.data.months.may;
    public selectedjune: boolean = this.data.months.jun;
    public selectedjuly: boolean = this.data.months.jul;
    public selectedaugust: boolean = this.data.months.aug;
    public selectedseptember: boolean = this.data.months.sep;
    public selectedoctober: boolean = this.data.months.oct;
    public selectednovember: boolean = this.data.months.nov;
    public selecteddecember: boolean = this.data.months.dec;

    public onChangeYear = function () { 
 // I set the values from my service.
        this.data.months.jan = false;
        this.data.months.feb = false;
        this.data.months.mar = false;
        this.data.months.apr = false;
        this.data.months.may = false;
        this.data.months.jun = false;
        this.data.months.jul = false;
        this.data.months.aug = false;
        this.data.months.sep = false;
        this.data.months.oct = false;
        this.data.months.nov = false;
        this.data.months.dec = false;
    }
```

But when I change the year, 2017 with select in December to 2018 December is checked...

Comment: Post working version of your sample code in codepen or plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkboxes are bound to `selectedjanuary` ... `selecteddecember`. They're not bound to `this.data.months.jan` ... `this.data.month.dec` Therefore, setting the latter to false will not change the value of the checkboxes.

When you write `public selectedjanuary: boolean = this.data.months.jan;` you take the *value* (and not the *reference*) of `this.data.months.jan` and put it in `selectedjanuary`. There is no link between the two, and thus modifying `this.data.months.jan` does **not** modify `selectedjanuary` again.

Comment: but selectedjanuary = myService

Comment: @EduBw You're confusing "pass by reference" and "pass by value". I've updated my answer to include this in more detail.